# PHP & HTML - How do I print something to a webpage, then remove it after a time?

Tags: php, html

Currently, I have this script activate when a button is pushed:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['reboot']))
{
    exec('"cmd /c echo wee! > C:\SWBF2\reboot"');
    print "<p>The server is rebooting!..</p>";
}
?>
```

So it creates a file called "reboot" then it prints "The server is rebooting!.." to the webpage. It works fine, but I want to remove the message printed after 5 seconds or so from the webpage.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Chayan is right. add class to the p tag and target remove it with jquery of JS

Comment: I'd write the page then make ajax requests. This way you could tell the user it is rebooting, and when it is back up.

Comment: Be sure to accept an answer by clicking on the checkbox and/or up vote if it resolves your issue.

Comment: I was hoping to do it with just PHP or something. I thought maybe even CSS3 could potentially do it with display: none; after a delay somehow. Hmm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured it out myself without any javascript!

Basically, I needed a CSS3 animation to load after a delay.

```
p.fadeout{
animation-name: fadeout;
animation-duration: 1s;
animation-delay: 5s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeout {
1% {opacity:1;display:block;}
100% {opacity:0;display:none;}
}
```

Comment: Only problem is it would be nice if it didn't occupy any space once it's faded.

Comment: You can click to accept your answer using the checkbox.  Also... I don't know how to make it not occupy space.  Usually display:none which will stop elements taking space up on the page.

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish what you want as minimally as possible, you can do this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['reboot']))
{
    exec('"cmd /c echo wee! > C:\SWBF2\reboot"');
    print "<p id='server-rebooting'>The server is rebooting!..</p>";
    ?>
    <script>
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('server-rebooting').style.display = 'none';

    }, 5000);
    </script>
<?}
?>
```

The JavaScript runs on the client side of the browser and the setTimeout function will execute the callback function to hide the element after 5 seconds.  The setTimeout function uses milliseconds and not seconds for the time value, so you can change 5000 to 3000 if you wanted to happen in 3 seconds.

If you are using jQuery you could accomplish it using the code below:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['reboot']))
{
    exec('"cmd /c echo wee! > C:\SWBF2\reboot"');
    print "<p id='server-rebooting'>The server is rebooting!..</p>";
    ?>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#server-rebooting').hide();
        }, 5000);
    });
    </script>
<?}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put response to a `<div>` and remove it using javascript after 5 sec. Using a javascript library such as jquery;

```
removeblock(function(){
  $('#reboot_response').remove();
}, 5000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript.  Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function hideFunction(textContainer) {
document.getElementById(textContainer).style.display = 'none';
}
</script> 

<p id="myHideText">This text will hide after 5 seconds!</p>
<script type="text/javascript">setTimeout("hideFunction('myHideText')",5000)</script>
```

This defines a function that will set the style's display property of an element to "none" to make it disappear.

The call itself is simple, you set a timeout (5 seconds in this case) and when that elapses it runs the function with the ID of the element you want to disappear passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

While I certainly think the Javascript approach is the way to go, if you want to use pure HTML code you can place this in the head section of your webpage:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
```

This command will reload a page after 5 seconds and since the button is not seen as pressed it will not display the message.

This of course takes a bit away from the nicer user experience that is available with Javascript. But depending on how your site is implemented it might just do the job for you.